# U.S. citizen working in China with earned income from France. Do I need to pay French taxes? I have never been to France

Tags: taxes, europe

U.S. citizen working in China with earned income from France. Do I need to pay French taxes? I have never been to France. I make $650K U.S. and only file state taxes in California as I have income property in that state however I do not file federal taxes in the U.S., China or France. Am I good or am I going to get in trouble? I would rather not find out down the road that I owe back taxes.

Comment: As a US citizen, you are subject to US federal taxes on your worldwide income, so if you have $650k income per year and do not file US federal taxes, that is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean that the earned income is "from France"? What kind of income is it?

Comment: If you’re resident and working in China you may have a tax liability there, although if a double taxation agreement exists between China and the US that may negate that. https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/peoples-republic-of-china/individual/foreign-tax-relief-and-tax-treaties You should get advice from a professional IMHO

Comment: if you make 650K a year, you should be able to afford a professional, instead of asking random internet people.

Answer (score 1):

> U.S. citizen working in China with earned income from France. Do I need to pay French taxes?

You haven't provided nearly enough information to even begin guessing what your tax liability may be in France. There is a [tax agreement](https://www.impots.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/media/10_conventions/chine/chine_accord-avec-la-chine-du-30.05.1984-abroge_fd_1741.pdf) between France and the PRC but a cursory reading suggests that it does grant Chinese residents a blanket exemption from all French taxes, if that's your question.

Beyond that, as noted in the comments, it seems your income is high enough and your situation complicated enough that it may be useful to hire a professional to help you deal with taxes.